# What is the best way to check >= and <= in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, operators

I have a number.

I then have an if statement that I want to go like this:

```
if (5 <= variable <= 10)
```

So if the number is between 5 and 10, the statement should be true.

What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: i think the `if (5 >= variable >= 10)` has the 5 and 10 reversed...

Comment: @ 動靜能量: you've got good eyes. I didn't even notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if ((variable >= 5) && (variable <= 10))` works.

If you do this frequently, consider defining a bounds function:

`function inBounds(value, min, max){
  return ((value >= min) && (value <= max));
}`

Answer (score 8):

it is

```
if (5 <= variable && variable <= 10)
```

Comment: +1 for keeping "variable" in the middle to resemble the original "5 <= variable <= 10"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `if ( 5>= variable >= 10 )` means `if(false)`
if you means variable between 5, 10 it should be `5 <= variable <=10`, and in javascript, the best convention is const value at left, which is from c language `if (v=1)`, `if (1=v)` problem. so the best is:

```
if (5 <= variable && 10 >= variable) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that at the first conditional false, it stops the checking and moves to the next statement.

Given that, you should examine the most often false condition and put it first.

```
if ((variable >= 5) && (variable <= 10))
```

if it is more likely to be less than 4 or

```
if ((variable <= 10) && (variable >= 5))
```

if the failure of 10 or greater is more likely to occur.